# Debug React Native App from Visual studio Emulator for Android

Tags: android, debugging, react-native, visual-studio-emulator

I am running my React Native app in Visual Studio Emulator for Android. Can someone tell me how can i debug my js code ? In Android studio simulator we have options to remote debug. But from Visual studio Emulator how can i debug..Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have chrome installed, then you can use the chrome debugger to debug your js code.
First 
 Mac: command + M
 Window: control + M
Then click debug js remotely; It will open a tab in chrome, then right click and select inspect, switch to the console tab. Any statement you console will appear there.

Comment: Ya..I have chrome installed.but when  i press control+m nothing happens. if i press 'r' twice ,my app is getting is reloaded .but pressing ctrl+m makes no changes.:-( . Do i need to change something in settings?

Comment: Go to your emulator and press control + M

Comment: @Thara what happens when you press ctl+m? Can you seen error something similar to this => `no access control allow origin chrome`

Comment: @Revansiddh If i press ctrl+m. nothing happens. No error..i can see only my app. no other changes.

Comment: Are you on Mac or Windows?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can debug your code.

First one : Using visual studio debug menu.

- Press `ctrl+shift+D` to open up debug menu and select `Attach to Packager` or select 4th item on the left in visual studio.

This allows you to set break points and debug code as you see in Android Studio.

Second one : Using [React Native Debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Second option is only for Mac OS ?

Comment: No it supports windows too. https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/releases

Comment: No problem. You can accept / upvote the answer for others to help :)